# Rancher Agent Could not Connect OpenSSL SSL_connect error

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have rancher server and I tried to add existing cluster as agent to my Rancher via domain adress. The Linux Machine can reach my domaing without any problem, however the rancher agent pod throws that error:

```
ERROR: https://[MY_DOMAIN]/ping is not accessible (OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to [MY_DOMAIN]:443)
```

However on the machine I can reach without any problem that only occurs on pod.

Comment: Got the same issue, did you manage to find a solution?